# Syntax for SQL on how to order by best match with most words using CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, search

Im currently amending the opencart search feature, this is a simplified version of the code without the PHP, Im looking to order my results by the most matched words. I have looked at other questions but cant seem to grasp how to use `CASE` in SQL to simply prioritise my matches.
Is it possible someone could show me the syntax

```
SELECT id from oc_products where 
  product_description LIKE '%my search keywords%' 
  OR product_description LIKE '%my%' 
  OR product_description LIKE '%search%' 
  OR product_description LIKE '%keywords%' 
ORDER BY
   CASE 
   WHEN product_description LIKE '%my search keywords%'
   WHEN product_description LIKE '%my search&'
  WHEN product_description LIKE '%my&'
  WHEN product_description LIKE '%search&'
  WHEN product_description LIKE '%keywords&',
  ASC
```

Im aware that my syntax is totally off but Im not sure how to implement `THEN` within that code to allow for prioritizing my results in the above order.

Thank you

Comment: so you want do to order by data in accordance with their appearances with like

Comment: well I simply want the best matched ones to appear first, at the moment one with "my search keywords" might appear half way down the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***First solution :***  `CASE`

```
SELECT id 
FROM oc_products 
WHERE product_description LIKE '%my search keywords%' 
   OR product_description LIKE '%my%' 
   OR product_description LIKE '%search%' 
   OR product_description LIKE '%keywords%' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN product_description LIKE '%my search keywords%' THEN 0
              WHEN product_description LIKE '%my search&' THEN 1
              WHEN product_description LIKE '%my&' THEN 2
              WHEN product_description LIKE '%search&' THEN 3
              WHEN product_description LIKE '%keywords&' THEN 4
         END DESC
```

***Second solution :***  listing conditions in `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT id 
FROM oc_products 
WHERE product_description LIKE '%my search keywords%' 
   OR product_description LIKE '%my%' 
   OR product_description LIKE '%search%' 
   OR product_description LIKE '%keywords%' 
ORDER BY product_description LIKE '%my search keywords%' DESC
       , product_description LIKE '%my search&' DESC
       , product_description LIKE '%my&' DESC
       , product_description LIKE '%search&' DESC
       , product_description LIKE '%keywords&' DESC
```

Comment: Thank you , your new top answer worked, but for some reason I had to put in `DESC` after `END` for it to go in the right order. Either way thats perfect thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id from oc_products where 
  product_description LIKE '%my search keywords%' 
  OR product_description LIKE '%my%' 
  OR product_description LIKE '%search%' 
  OR product_description LIKE '%keywords%' 
GROUP BY product_description ASC
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id 
FROM oc_products 
WHERE product_description LIKE '%my search keywords%' 
   OR product_description LIKE '%my%' 
   OR product_description LIKE '%search%' 
   OR product_description LIKE '%keywords%' 

ORDER BY product_description LIKE '%my search keywords%' desc
, product_description LIKE '%my search%' desc 
, product_description LIKE '%my%' desc 
, product_description LIKE '%search%' desc
, product_description LIKE '%keywords%' desc;
```

SQL fiddle here:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b043/4